# After posting my question, I realized that I have solved it. What follows?

Tags: discussion

Link [Exponential distribution: Calculate $E(Y^a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003369/exponential-distribution-calculate-eya)

After asking a question I realized how to solve it. A fellow user already has a comment on the question. What is the conventional courtesy? Deleting, or answer my own question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can answer it!

The [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) has a nice couple paragraphs on this (pasted below), but essentially it's great to share what you've learned with the community, so answering your own questions is definitely encouraged. If you're feeling particularly curious, check out [self-answer](/questions/tagged/self-answer) for questions about this very process.

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time.
>
> You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

Just make sure you post your answer in the answer box, rather than as an edit. I've seen that a few times, and it makes it kind of difficult for users in the future to find.

Answer (score 7):

Matthew Haugen is correct that you can answer your own question. This is the right thing to do **when** the problem you faced and your answer would be **helpful to other people.** Post the answer formally as an answer (and not as an edit of the question).

If the problem and its solution would not be helpful to others, then the best thing to do for the benefit of the community is to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Louis is right about Matthew Haugen being correct.

Answering your own question adds info and future help which other users can make use of.
As long as it *is not* a dupe question, as then you're not adding quality or useful content, you're just polluting the site and causing work for community to mop up.

If it turns out to be a dupe, just delete it, possibly giving the Q & A on the dupe a friendly nod (upvote).